# Rails: Redirecting all routes in a namespace to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm looking to redirect all routes in a Rails namespace to the root path. Here's what I have so far. It works, but I wanted to see if I could get it into a single line:

```
namespace "old_namespace" do
  match "/", :to => redirect("/")
  match "*path", :to => redirect("/")
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Rails 3

```
namespace :old_namespace do
  match '(*any)' , to: redirect('/')
end
```

### Rails 4

```
namespace :old_namespace do
  match '(*any)' , to: redirect('/'), via: [:get, :post]
end
```

Comment: this worked for me, though had to add  `via: [:get, :post]` to avoid " ERROR -- : You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method." - Rails 4

Comment: This answer was for rails 3 :)